# Как создавать связи между хранилищами Ext.data.Store в памяти?

Tags: extjs

Я создал два хранилища. Указал связь один-ко-многим (hasMany: "Detail"). Указал что они связываются через поле "pid" хранилища "detailStore" ({ name: "pid", reference: "Master" }).

Вопрос, где прописать связь двух существующих хранилищ?

Вот код (песочница https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1735):

```
    var proxy = {
        type: "memory",
        reader: {
            type: "json"
        }
    };

    Ext.define("Master", {
        extend: "Ext.data.Model",
        fields: ["id", "title"],
        hasMany: "Detail"
    });

    Ext.define("Detail", {
        extend: "Ext.data.Model",
        fields: ["id", { name: "pid", reference: "Master" }, "title"]
    });

    var masterStore = Ext.create("Ext.data.Store", {
        proxy: proxy,
        model: "Master",
        data: [
            { id: 1, title: "Группа 1" },
            { id: 2, title: "Группа 2" },
            { id: 3, title: "Группа 3" }
        ]
    });

    var detailStore = Ext.create("Ext.data.Store", {
        proxy: proxy,
        model: "Detail",
        data: [
            { id: 1, pid: 1, title: "Запись 1" },
            { id: 2, pid: 1, title: "Запись 2" },
            { id: 3, pid: 1, title: "Запись 3" },
            { id: 4, pid: 2, title: "Запись 4" },
            { id: 5, pid: 2, title: "Запись 5" },
            { id: 6, pid: 2, title: "Запись 6" }
        ]
    });

    console.log(masterStore.getAt(1).details().getCount()); // Выдает нуль, хотя записей там три на каждую группу.
```

Answer (score 1):

Ура, мне ответили на официальном сайте
https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?309480-How-to-create-links-between-Ext.data.Store-storage-in-memory&p=1130395

Вот песочница https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/177f
И вот код:

```
    var proxy = {
        type: "memory",
        reader: {
            type: "json"
        }
    };

    var session = Ext.create("Ext.data.Session");

    Ext.define("Master", {
        extend: "Ext.data.Model",
        fields: ["id", "title"]
    });

    Ext.define("Detail", {
        extend: "Ext.data.Model",
        fields: ["id", {
            name: "pid",
            reference: {
                type: "Master",
                role: "Master"
            }
        }, "title"]
    });

    var masterStore = Ext.create("Ext.data.Store", {
        proxy: proxy,
        model: "Master",
        session: session,
        data: [{
            id: 1,
            title: "Группа 1"
        }, {
            id: 2,
            title: "Группа 2"
        }, {
            id: 3,
            title: "Группа 3"
        }]
    });

    var detailStore = Ext.create("Ext.data.Store", {
        proxy: proxy,
        model: "Detail",
        session: session,
        data: [{
            id: 1,
            pid: 1,
            title: "Запись 1"
        }, {
            id: 2,
            pid: 1,
            title: "Запись 2"
        }, {
            id: 3,
            pid: 1,
            title: "Запись 3"
        }, {
            id: 4,
            pid: 2,
            title: "Запись 4"
        }, {
            id: 5,
            pid: 2,
            title: "Запись 5"
        }, {
            id: 6,
            pid: 2,
            title: "Запись 6"
        }]
    });

    console.log(masterStore.getAt(1).details().getCount());
```

Оказывается в ссылке надо прописать role: "Master"